# 500 internal server error AJAX POST request laravel server

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am trying to make ajax post requests to the server so that i can get data to update my view

**My Ajax code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        method:'POST',
        url:'{{route('pusher')}}',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        },
        data:{
            mac:'{{$slaves['mac']}}'
        },
        success:function(response)
        {
            alert(response);
        },
        error:function(iqXHR,testStatus,errorThrown)
        {
            alert('error');
        }
    })
});
```

**The API**

```
public function getSlaveDataJson(Request $request)
{
    $temp = [
        'action'=>'list_slave',
        'mac'=> $request->mac,
        'type' => 'all',
        'appkey' => '3E6157D4409B28627586E37F7B1E656E'
    ];

    json_encode($temp);

    $response = Curl::to('http://103.31.82.46/open/open.php')
    ->withContentType('application/json')
    ->withData($temp)
    ->asJson(true)
    ->withHeader('Postman-Token: d5988618-676e-430c-808e-7e2f6cec88fc')
    ->withHeader('cache-control: no-cache')
    ->post();

        self::destroy($request->mac);
        self::addAllSlaves($response);

    return $response;
}
```

The API returns json data back if i run it with postman but i get 500 internal server error when i run it from ajax. help.

P.S
will using websockets instead of this help me in creating an automatically updating table?

Comment: please show your route defination

Comment: try to return json in response like   return response()->json([
            'data' => $response
          ]);

Comment: I got It to work by using Fetch API!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got It to work by using Fetch API!